# site-package of python3 not found

Tags: python-3.6, python-2.x, site-packages

I am trying to find where is the site-package for Python3

```
    ➜  ~ python3 -m site --user-site
    /Users/macbookpro/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages

    ➜  ~ cd /Users/macbookpro/Library/Python/3.6.
    cd: no such file or directory: /Users/macbookpro/Library/Python/3.6.
```

However, as Python2.7 it works well

```
    ➜  Python python2 -m site --user-site           
    /Users/macbookpro/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
    ➜  Python cd /Users/macbookpro/Library/Python/2.7
    ➜  2.7
```

Why there is no such site-package for Python3?

Comment: try:-  which python3 command and locate python first

Comment: if its mac, it must be in below directory:-
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions

Comment: Yeah, I am using Mac, and your path can be found. But where is site-package for python3?@Mr.J

Comment: excellent.! now look for path
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Comment: Great! Now my problem has solved. Thank you! ^ ^ @ Mr.J

Comment: i am pasting as answer, put marked as answer so it will useful for others

Answer (score 0):

try:-
 `which python3` command and locate python first 
if its mac, it must be in below directory:- 
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages`